# for loop only executes once

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my code. My outer loop only iterates once instead of ten times. I know this because `System.out.println(i + " " + word)` only happens once. I do not understand why.

edit: I've added my full method that this is included in. Part of a program to create a character array that makes a word search puzzle. rows = 23. cols = 11. Word[] is an array that includes starting row and col value for each word entered into the array, if the word will be horizontal or vertical, etc.

```
public static char[][] createPuzzle(int rows, int cols, Word[] words) {

    char[][] grid = new char[rows][cols];
    for (Word h : words) {
        System.out.println(h.getWord());
    }
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i<=9; i++){
            String word = words[i].getWord();
            System.out.println(i + " " + word);
            boolean hor = words[i].isHorizontal();
            if (hor == true){
                for(int j = 0; j <= word.length(); j++){
                    grid[words[i].getRow()][words[i].getCol()+j] = word.charAt(j);
                }
            } else if (hor == false){
                for(int k = 0; k <= word.length(); k++){
                    grid[words[i].getCol()][words[i].getRow()+k] = word.charAt(k);
                }
            } 
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //catches exception
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: Why is it only going through the loop once instead of 10 times

Comment: Allegedly his `System.out.println(i + " " + word);` only executes once.

Comment: Are you getting any errors and/or exceptions?

Comment: correct, Gendarme. I can find no explanation for why the loop is being exited prior to executing 10 times

Comment: no errors or exceptions. I am using a try-catch to handle StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Create and post your best [mcve] as this will give us the best chances of helping you figure this out.

Comment: There is no detectable error in this code-sample. I think you will need to provide some more information.

Comment: Off-Topic: Please use if(hor) instead of if(hor == true) and if(!hor) instead of if(hor == false)

Comment: If I could, I would vote to reopen this question. He has provided enough information to solve this problem. Actually it was obvious from the start; I do not know how we all missed it.

Or alternatively, mark it as a duplicate, since there are lot of other questions that explain `StringOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: `catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //catches exception
    }` Get rid of this nonsense. You should never catch those exceptions and you should never ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the following syntax:

```
} catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //catches exception
}
```

What happens:

1. Somethere in your code was thrown an exception `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The exception breaks your `for` loop.
2. `catch` block cathes the exception, and...
3. does **nothing**, just ignores is and goes on.

So, you should add at least something like this

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

at your `catch` block.

Never ignore exceptions!